# ESP8266 reading request from local database

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I was not to expert with Nodemcu or IOT. I'm trying to read data from database with request by Nodemcu; it works but it showing that I don't want to get.

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = ".....";
const char* password = ".....";
const char* host = "......";

WiFiClient client;
const int httpPort = 8000;
String url;
unsigned long timeout;
  
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    //return;
  }

  url = "/request/55";
  
  Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);

  // This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }

// Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while(client.available()) {
      String a;
      a = client.readString();
      Serial.println(a);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
  Serial.println();
}
```

URL: /request/55 only echo value "12", I'm trying to use `client.readString()` and this the result :

[image: the result I got]

It is work, but I just only want that value "12". How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to get data from database, first you need to change the result from URL. In this condition I change result "12" to "data=12", then on Nodemcu:

```cpp
while (client.available()) {
  String a;
  if (client.find("data=") {
    a = client.parseInt(a);
    Serial.println(a);
  }
}
```

This is the result:

[image: result in serial monitor]

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing the HTTP protocol yourself. That's why you're getting HTTP headers back. You don't need to do that and probably shouldn't.

Use the `ESP8266HTTPClient` library. It implements HTTP correctly so that you don't have to. You can find examples at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples